Is it possible to make garbage disposal drainage pipe longer without effecting P-Trap?
I am installing a water filtration system under my kitchen sink. The filtration system requires a small drainage line to be drilled into the vertical drainage pipe from my disposal to the P-Trap (See attached picture).

Unfortunately my drainage pipe between my disposal and P-Trap is very short. I don't think there is enough room for the saddle bracket to fit. (The red "X" is where it would have to go).

My question is, would I be able to make the disposal drainage pipe longer to provide enough room to install the drainage saddle bracket? This would lower the P-Trap, so I am wondering if it would position the P-Trap too low from the wall drain opening to be effective?
I asked the company if the drainage line could be installed after the P-Trap on the horizontal pipe, and it would not be correct. If I were able to fit the saddle bracket on the vertical pipe where the red "X" is, the concern is that it could get clogged.
Thank you I appreciate the help!

I think the following would work:

Disconnect the dishwasher drain hose from the disposal.
Attach an extension drain pipe to the dishwasher connection on the disposal, long enough to add the drain saddle, or possibly even with some sort of "T" connector so you don't actually use a saddle (i.e., avoid actually drilling into the pipe.)
Attach the dishwasher drain hose to the end of the extension.
Make sure the dishwasher hose is properly in a high-loop configuration - i.e., it should loop up under the counter - that is critical to provide an air gap for the dishwasher drain.


I didn't think of that. Do you think I would hear the water draining into the disposal (like when the dishwasher drains water during a wash cycle) constantly? Would an option be to put a longer straight drain pipe from the disposal and swivel the p-trap? Thanks!
